# DropBox like software that lets me host my own files

Tags: sync, dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to Dropbox (on my server)?](https://superuser.com/questions/128590/alternative-to-dropbox-on-my-server)

I have a good home server with tons of storage. I have FTP and SVN setup on it but I miss the convenience of DropBox for file syncing. Does anyone know of any programs similar to DropBox that allow you to host your own server instead of requiring you to use their cloud service?

Comment: I know not of anything like this, but I would be extremely interested if someone else has heard of relatively simple software that could do this.

Comment: There's an exact duplicate of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/128590/alternative-to-dropbox-on-my-server You'll find some more interesting answers there!

Comment: The duplicate is now returning 404...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iFolder](http://ifolder.com/ifolder) is a very cool product that I wish more developers would get behind. You configure a server and then you setup any folder or folders to sync to your account on the server. I was originally a Novell product as were all the kablink applications and were open sourced.

Answer (score 1):

[AeroFS](http://www.aerofs.com/) can work across the LAN without a centralized server set up, and without using their severs.

Answer (score 0):

I was debating to make this a comment or an answer.

[Sparkleshare](http://sparkleshare.org/) is a program that is supposed to do this, but it's still a bit buggy and relies on a git backend, which apparently isn't that great for large binary files. It's something you could look into if you wanted, but isn't there yet.

What I ended up doing is set up my own shared folders with rsync, that I can synch by running a script.